# mvc 4 hosted in classic asp authentication

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic

We have a site in classic ASP.

We are in the process of converting pieces of this site MVC4. There are areas that require authentication.

There is an authentication process in the main site.

How can i check in the MVC4 areas if the user is authenticated in the main site?

Comment: how do you stor in the classic asp part that the user is authenticated?

Comment: As i see it, it stores it in cookies. It checks the Session("email") with the cookies "email". I know it might be a bad idea, but i am not responsible, and this is going to change once the whole site is in new technology.

Comment: well than just check the Cookie? checking a classic asp session variable from asp.net is possible but not as easys as to check a Client side Cookie...

Comment: @ulluoink Your comment was most valuable, because it lead me look into how the authentication was happening in the classic asp part. This lead me to actually find the solution i was looking for. Please add it as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you store in the classic asp part that the user is authenticated?

when stored in a Cookie than just check the Cookie.

checking a classic asp session variable from asp.net is possible but not as easys as to check a Client side Cookie...

Comment: Thanks, for the help. Though it was there all the time, i just didn't think to check it... You made me search where i should have searchd in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You can put an authentication attribute over either your controller or a specific action method for a user of a specific role.

[See Tutorial about it here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7)

Comment: Hi, this tutorial, though useful, seems to explain how to handle authentication within MVC. What i need is leave the authentication process to the classic ASP (Main site) and let the MVC (Folder within the Main Site) know if the user is authenticated or not.